# Is there a rule for line-breaking a name designation?

Tags: typography, layout

I've searched, but to no avail. Is there a rule (or what is your opinion) on line-breaking a person's designations?

Sometimes client's have many designations which extends the line making it very difficult to lay out a business card for example. Is it appropriate to put the designations on the next line?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by designations? Degrees? Any group of different data type can start on a new line.

Comment: It really depends on the layout, design, typography, content, etc.

Comment: @Webster: if you rewrite your comment as an answer, then the OP can accept it.